# Admob w/Spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, admob

I am trying to get a banner ad showing up on a certain scene every time a user loads it. I know I have to position it programmatically here.

So far I:

```
import GoogleMobileAds
```

and then I:

```
let BannerAd = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)
BannerAd.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 50)
BannerAd.delegate = self
BannerAd.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-##/##"
BannerAd.rootViewController = self

let request = GADRequest()
request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID, "*************************"]

BannerAd.load(request)
view?.addSubview(BannerAd)
```

But I get the following errors:

Cannot assign value of type 'GameOverScene' to type 'UIViewController?'

and I'm putting this code inside of my init for this scene (it's a gameOver scene that I transition to when the player wins/losses).

Is there anyway to get this banner ad to show up or do I need to use UIKit here?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just need to add the GADBannerViewDelegate protocol to your class.

```
    class GameOverScene: SKScene, GADBannerViewDelegate {
       ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to get this banner ad to show up or do I need to use UIKit here?

You should use UIKit here. Go to your storyboard, add a `GADBannerView` to your view controller's view. Add an outlet to your `ViewController.swift` file. In `viewDidLoad`, you can then set `rootViewController` to `self` and do other configurations.